# Angular write unit test for Confirmation Dialogue (modal in modal)

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a requirement where once user clicks on Delete button a confirmation window pop up with option to Cancel or Delete. Challenge here, is that Delete button is on another popup-dialog.component.ts

The first dialog with comments and delete option
[image]

The second dialog
[image]

I need to test two scenarios, where nothing gets deleted when cancel button clicked.
One comment deleted when Delete Comment button clicked.
How can we write unit test for this in angular. The UI is something like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-confirmation-dialog?file=app/app.component.html

My approach:

confirmation-dialog.component.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="dismiss()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="decline()">{{ btnCancelText }}</button>
    <button type="button" id="delete-confirmation-id" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="accept()">{{ btnOkText }}</button>
  </div>
```

confirmation-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirmation-dialog.component.html',
})
export class ConfirmationDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() message: string;
  @Input() btnOkText: string;
  @Input() btnCancelText: string;

  constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public decline() {
    this.activeModal.close(false);
  }

  public accept() {
    this.activeModal.close(true);
  }

  public dismiss() {
    this.activeModal.dismiss();
  }

}
```

confirmation-dialog.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './confirmation-dialog.component';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmationDialogService {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  public confirm(
    title: string,
    message: string,
    btnOkText: string = 'OK',
    btnCancelText: string = 'Cancel',
    dialogSize: 'sm'|'lg' = 'sm'): Promise<boolean> {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { size: dialogSize });
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = title;
    modalRef.componentInstance.message = message;
    modalRef.componentInstance.btnOkText = btnOkText;
    modalRef.componentInstance.btnCancelText = btnCancelText;
    modalRef.componentInstance.css = "DeleteConfirmDialog"; //I am not sure if I can even use this to retrieve using By.css("DeleteConfirmDialog")

    return modalRef.result;
  }

}
```

popup-dialog.component.html

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
 <div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="creator.value === userId">
   <a id="delete-id-{{i}}" href="javascript:void(0);" *ngIf="deleteflag" (click)="deleteCommentConfirmDialog(id.value)">
                  Delete
                </a>
   </ng-container>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div
```

popup-dialog.component.ts

The method called when delete button is clicked

```
 deleteCommentConfirmDialog(commentId : number) {
    this.activeModal.close('Close'); // Is used to hide the first popup
    this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Please Confirm', 'Do you really want to.?')
    .then((confirmed) => {
      if(confirmed) {
        console.log('User confirmed to delete:');
        this.delete(commentId);
      } else {
        console.log('User cancelled');
        this.cancel();
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('User dismissed the dialog (e.g., by using ESC, clicking the cross icon, or clicking outside the dialog)');
      this.cancel();
    })
  }
```

popup.component.spec.ts

```
it('should call confirmation dialog when delete button clicked',() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PopupDialogComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let confirmDialog : ConfirmationDialogComponent;
    confirmDialog = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("DeleteConfirmDialog")).componentInstance;
    let accept = spyOn(confirmDialog,"accept").and.callThrough();
    component.deleteCommentConfirmDialog(101);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let btnOkText = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.tcs-comment-delete-confirmation');
    btnOkText.click();
    expect(accept).toHaveBeenCalled();
    //expect(component.confirmed).toEqual(true);
  })
```

ng test is failing with this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'componentInstance')
Line: fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("DeleteConfirmDialog")).componentInstance;

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: @Shashank Vivek , Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

With `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(...)` you can only find elements that are children of the component you created via `TestBed.createComponent(...)`. This means in your case only children of the `PopupDialogComponent`.

To find the ok button of the confirm dialog (or anything else inside document body), use this:

```
window.document.body.querySelector(...)
```

This will return an HTMLElement and you can interact with it, e.g. click a button. It will not give access to the component instance, but your test will anyhow be more valuable if you interact and assert by using natural interfaces, i.e. the user interface, @Input or @Output, backend APIs, method calls of mocked services...

In your case, I would suggest to get the ok button with the above method, click on it and assert that the comment got deleted (or that a backend api was called to delete the comment, I did not see that part of the code). Instead of asserting that a method of the confirm dialog component got called.

```
// click delete button

// maybe assert that confirm dialog is open
// click ok in confirm dialog

// assert that comment is deleted
```

Comment: So, to read confirmDialog = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("DeleteConfirmDialog")).componentInstance; I should try window.document.body.querySelector('DeleteConfirmDialog')     var window = window.document.body.querySelector("DeleteConfirmDialog");
    spyOn(window, "confirm");
    expect(window.confirm).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Please Confirm");   Getting error  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document') at line window.document.body.querySelector('DeleteConfirmDialog')

Comment: it will not get you the component instance, I just extended my answer, hope that helps

Comment: Step 1 is to get OK button and I am using this , but it is giving error here var window = window.document.body.querySelector("btnOkText");         TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
            at UserContext.<anonymous>

Comment: could you try using a different variable name than "window"? 
var someOtherName = window.document.body.querySelector("btnOkText");

Comment: var test = window.document.body.querySelector("btnOkText");  this works. So, it returns an HTMLElement but how to interact with it for calling button click.

Comment: just do: test.click() (and probably you need to trigger a change detection afterwards via fixture.detectChanges())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245697/discussion-between-likegreen-and-slim).

Comment: var test = document.querySelector(".modal-content");  this is what displays html element. But ng-container code will not be shown, it seems so can't proceed.